# InfoPath Forms Services installed but not configurable

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I want to build a InfoPath form which works with a SharePoint Workflow but the Problem is, if i'm trying to establish a connection between the InfoPath Designer and my SharePoint 2010 Instance i get an error saying that i need an Server with acitvated InfoPath Forms Services..

I did a little reading a wanted to configure the InfoPath Forms Service but i can't access it through the central administratiom from the SharePoint. I checked and the Service is properly installed and active. But with the Configuration Wizard in the Browser Interface or the Gerenal Appilcation Management nowhere the InfoPath Service is listed..

Anyone an Idea? The Configuration Wizard in the Central Administration displays me a blank page..

Comment: Since i did some reading i found out that this behaviour only occurs if you're using an pre-RTM license key.. you have to install the feature manually.. more infos can be found here: http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/06/15/wheres-infopath-forms-services-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, InfoPath Forms Services are missing if pre-RTM license key is used. For more information check the link in the comments.